# Separar front-end e back-and do executável

Tags: c#, wpf

Minha ideia é separar a aplicação em três arquivos distintos, no arquivo `MinhaAppBackend.dll`, ficará, como o nome sugere, todas as classes e demais elementos que fazem parte do back-end da aplicação (Model, ViewModel, Daos, etc).
No arquivo `MinhaAppFrontend.dll` ficará tudo relacionado a parte GUI(WPF) da aplicação (janela principal, diálogos, janelas filhas, etc).
O arquivo `MinhaApp.exe` será apenas o ponto de partida da aplicação, ele será apenas o responsável por chamar a janela principal que está na biblioteca `MinhaAppFrontend.dll`. Ao contrário do que a maioria faz que é deixar o front-end no arquivo `.exe` com o método `main` gerado na hora da compilação. No meu caso ele será "burro", terá a única função de ser o start da aplicação.

Para o front-end, minha ideia é um projeto do tipo `WPF User Control Library`, que compila elementos GUI(WPF) para uma `dll`.
O projeto que irá gerar o arquivo `.exe` faz referência a `dll` contendo o front-end e "chama" a janela principal. Eu ainda não implementei esse "modelo de solução", apenas idealizei.

O que eu quero?

Saber a opinião da turma sobre essa minha ideia de "design de solução", ou seja, se isso pode me trazer algum problema ou alguma dificuldade extra ou se pode ser incompatível com o MVVM (analisando sem colocar a mão na massa acho que não).
Também quero saber como seria o método main para carregar e exibir a janela principal que está na `dll`.

Estou postando o [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AgT_-IcaL0H3gqFlmnR8VxvUHIzktA) para um projeto demo, caso alguém precise ver na prática o que eu pretendo.
A solução tem dois projetos um deletes é um `Console Application` que gera um executável o outro é um `WPF User Control Library` que gera uma janela em uma dll.

Answer (score 1):

Matheus no caso de WPF procure trabalhar com MVVM, uma vez que WPF não trabalha com "Controllers". Você pode até usar o mesmo princípio da estrutura do MVC, mas para isso crie diretórios que "abriguem" as camadas. Para usar essa "janela" dentro do MainWindow use o conceito de UserControls em que você pode criar componentes e carregá-los dentro da Window.

Comment: Pera ai, não entendi. Eu coloco essa linha onde ( `Process.Start("caminho do .exe");` ) ?

Comment: se você coloca-lo dentro do MainWindow.xaml.cs ele irá executar o arquivo .exe

Comment: Tinha entendido a sua pergunta de outra maneira. Dê uma olhada na correção.. me perdoe

Comment: Você continua não entendendo, não existe outra janela, essa é a única e principal janela da aplicação. A diferença é que ela está em um projeto do tipo Class Library (DLL).
O projeto que será o executável é o projeto denominado `Main`. No projeto `Main` não existe nada, nem GUI, nem regra de negócios, acesso a dados, nada. `Main` será apenas o responsável por "starta" a aplicação. Ou seja, chamar a janela principal do programa que no caso é `MainWindows` e está em uma DLL.

Comment: Desculpem pela enorme demora em dar um retorno, realmente tive que parar esse projeto por um tempo.
Percebi que essa pergunta não foi muito bem compreendida, por isso editei a pergunta por inteiro e ainda compartilhei um projeto demo.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve fazer com que o projeto **`Main`** receba **referências** dos outros projetos, a partir daí o projeto **`Main`** vai pode acessar todos os itens públicos dos outros projetos.

Dentro do projeto **`Main`**, clique em **References** e em **Add Reference**.

[image: Área de referências do projeto]

Na janela que vai abrir, escolha **Projects > Solution** no menu a esquerda e depois marque os projetos que você quer referenciar no **Main**

[image: Projetos para referenciar]

Comment: Desculpem pela enorme demora em dar um retorno, realmente tive que parar esse projeto por um tempo.

Exato, isso eu já fiz. Preciso saber como o método `main` deve chamar a janela wpf que está na `dll`.
Percebi que essa pergunta não foi muito bem compreendida, por isso editei a pergunta por inteiro e ainda compartilhei um projeto demo.